# Combinatorics problem regarding symmetry

Tags: combinatorics

Problem 10:  let $\omega_n = \{1,2,3,....,n\}$. How many ways are there to choose an ordered pair $(A,B)$ of subsets of $\omega_n$ such that $A \cap B = \emptyset$?. Show this in two distinct ways.

One way is to try to comeup with an expresion that represents  all the subsets of cardinality r that can be in A times the sets that can be made out of the remaning elements which correspond to B. $${n \choose r}* 2^{n-r}$$

With this in mind, if we have a set of n elements, the total number of ordered pairs we can get is

$${n \choose n}*2^0 + {n \choose{n-1}}*2^1 + {n \choose {n-2}}*2^2 + ..... + {n \choose 0}*2^n$$

Is that correct?. What would be another way?. I think there is a more powerful formula which requires a more exhaustive search for symmetry .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is correct.
Notice that your formula is actually the binomial expansion of $(1+2)^n = 3^n$. Considering this, can we find an explanation directly to the formula $3^n$?

The answer is yes, and it is quite elegant. Each element from $\omega_n$ is either in $A, B$ or in neither. Thus each of the $n$ elements have 3 different places where they can be, and each choice is independent. Thus there are $3^n$ combinations.

Comment: Cool, that's the symmetry I was looking for.